# Debug with Function Framework python with Visual Studio Code Break points

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am asking a question but it may sound silly,
I am developing Gooogle cloud function testing locally in in visual studio with Function-framework. I am able to run it properly in local environment. But I want to Debug it too using the Breakpoints in visual studio code
Currently i run it with
functions-framework --source=user.py --target=user
I wan to use visual studio break points or any other IDE is also okay anybody has idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ive seen ways to do it in vs code, Im just not sure how to do it. I know you can do it in your Dev tools from the browser. Sources in your Dev tools should let you do this.

Comment: so you are telling any extension or something is there in DEV tools ?